# Avoid SPAN tag in react-translate-component

Tags: reactjs

I am working on multilingual ReactJS application, for internationalization i am using [react-translate-component](https://github.com/martinandert/react-translate-component)

I want to display a country drop-down in my application, below is the code what i am using

```
const Content = ({ }) => {
    const options = countryData.map((option, i) => (
       <option key={i} value={option}><Translate {...this.props} content={langKey} /></option>
    ));

    return (
        <select className="form-control" name="country" ref="country"  defaultValue={this.state.personData.countryCode} onChange={this.validateCountry} >
            <option value="empty-field">Country</option>
            {options}
        </select>
    );
};`
```

The above code works but it creates an extra span tag inside every option.

I have also came across that in the previous version of react their was an issue with the span tag, but i am also using the latest version of react i.e. 15.1.0

Is their a best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the answers

The solution i found was just add a component attribute in Translate tag, so below is the final code that worked!!

```
const Content = ({ }) => {
const options = countryData.map((option, i) => (
   <Translate {...this.props} key={i} value={option}> content={langKey} component="option" />
));

return (
    <select className="form-control" name="country" ref="country"  defaultValue={this.state.personData.countryCode} onChange={this.validateCountry} >
        <option value="empty-field">Country</option>
        {options}
    </select>
    );
};`
```

Thanks,

Dhiraj

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

Add property `unsafe={true}` to *Translate* component:

```
<Translate {...this.props} content={langKey} unsafe={true} />
```

Take into account this property ***should not be used*** if you are interpolating user's text input.

### Long answer

I faced the same issue in a different scenario where I had a translation entry with an interpolation param (max).

Translation entry (in *en.json*):

```
"invalid-timespan": "Time span cannot be longer than %(max)s months.",
```

*Translate* component instantiation:

```
<Translate {...this.props} content='invalid-timespan' max='3' />
```

The resulting message was:

```
Time span cannot be longer than
3
months.
```

I did a bit of research into react-translate-component and [react-interpolate-component](https://github.com/martinandert/react-interpolate-component) and found what I think is the cause of the issue.

The following code is an extract of the Interpolate component's [render](https://github.com/martinandert/react-interpolate-component/blob/master/index.js) method. As you can see, when `unsafe` is true, the content is concatenated as a unique string whereas when `unsafe` is false, the content is *pushed* to an array, generating three `<span>` elements:

```
if (unsafe) {
  var content = format.split(REGEXP).reduce(function(memo, match, index) {
    var html;
    ...
    memo += html;

    return memo;
  }, '');

  props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML = { __html: content };
} else {
  format.split(REGEXP).reduce(function(memo, match, index) {
    var child;
    ...
    memo.push(child);

    return memo;
  }, children);
}
```

Thus, adding `unsafe={true}` as indicated above, produced a unique `<span>` element:

```
Time span cannot be longer than 3 months.
```

**Caveats**:

- As indicated previously, don't use `unsafe` when interpolating user's text input.
- When using `unsafe` you are required to provide the interpolation values. For example, the following code will generate an error because of the missing interpolation value (`max='3'`):

  `<Translate {...this.props} content='invalid-timespan' />`